# Возможно ли загрузить документ в вк через api сразу публичным?

Tags: вконтакте

Загрузка документ проходит успешно, но через приложение его нельзя сделать публичным только в ручную?
Если загружать документ самому через сайт тогда указать что документ не приватный можно, а через апи насколько я понял это сделать нельзя?
https://vk.com/dev/docs.save